# Equipment maintenance tracking software

Tags: software-recommendation

I need software for equipment maintenance tracking, I am thinking of designing an Openoffice.org base database for this but It would probably save me a lot of time if something already exist to do this that is freely available. I would be happy if someone could point me to something, even if the software was not designed specifically for equipment maintenance tracking but could be repurposed in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe you are looking for is a fixed asset management system, you can find plenty of Linux based fams, but a lot of them are designed for enterprise so you will find that they are interesting to set up and most likely web based.

I recommend checking out some of the items in this list:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fams/